# How to fix NULL when fitting train_data in linear regression model?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am using spark.ml to run a linear regression model. But whenever i fit my train data to the model it gives me an error of scala.MatchError: [null,1.0,[136.0,21.0,25.0]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)

I tried removing all the null values and all the empty values from my dataset to make sure i dont get the null but that didnt work

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("listings").getOrCreate()

listings_df = spark.read.csv('data/listings.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
listings_df = listings_df.filter('price != " "')
listings_df = listings_df.filter('room_type != " "')
listings_df = listings_df.filter('neighbourhood != " "')
listings_df.na.drop()

listings_df.head(1)
listings_df.printSchema()
display(listings_df.select("number_of_reviews", "price").groupBy("price"))

from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'neighbourhood', outputCol = 'neighbour_cat')
indexed = indexer.fit(listings_df).transform(listings_df)
indexed.head(3)

indexer2 = StringIndexer(inputCol = "room_type", outputCol = "room_cat")
indexed2 = indexer2.fit(indexed).transform(indexed)
indexed2.head(3)

from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ['neighbour_cat',
 'room_cat', 'minimum_nights'], outputCol = "features", handleInvalid = "keep")

output = assembler.transform(indexed2)

output.select('features','price').show()

final_data = output.select(['features','price'])

from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
final_data = final_data.withColumn("price",final_data["price"].cast(DoubleType()))
final_data.show()

train_data,test_data = final_data.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
price_lr = LinearRegression(labelCol = "price")

trained_model = price_lr.fit(test_data)


this is how my schema looks 

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- host_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- host_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- neighbourhood_group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- neighbourhood: string (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: string (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: string (nullable = true)
 |-- room_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: string (nullable = true)
 |-- minimum_nights: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- number_of_reviews: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_review: string (nullable = true)
 |-- reviews_per_month: string (nullable = true)
 |-- calculated_host_listings_count: double (nullable = true)
 |-- availability_365: integer (nullable = true)
```

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-47356d511385> in <module>
----> 1 trained_model = price_lr.fit(test_data)

C:\apachespark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

C:\apachespark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 295         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    296         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    297         return self._copyValues(model)

C:\apachespark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    290         """
    291         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 292         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):

C:\apachespark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\apachespark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\apachespark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1149.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 90.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 90.0 (TID 90, localhost, executor driver): scala.MatchError: [null,1.0,[136.0,21.0,25.0]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression$$anonfun$train$1$$anonfun$8.apply(LinearRegression.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression$$anonfun$train$1$$anonfun$8.apply(LinearRegression.scala:325)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2158)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1.apply(RDD.scala:1098)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1161)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.WeightedLeastSquares.fit(WeightedLeastSquares.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression$$anonfun$train$1.apply(LinearRegression.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression$$anonfun$train$1.apply(LinearRegression.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$$anonfun$11.apply(Instrumentation.scala:183)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.train(LinearRegression.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.train(LinearRegression.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: [null,1.0,[136.0,21.0,25.0]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression$$anonfun$train$1$$anonfun$8.apply(LinearRegression.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression$$anonfun$train$1$$anonfun$8.apply(LinearRegression.scala:325)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: looking at the error message, it looks like your label column is null. Can you try replacing this line: final_data = output.select(['features','price'])
with
final_data = output.select(['features','price']).where(col("price").isNotNull())

Comment: Hi, Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: yess i fixed this issue!